# Is it possible to generate a subca or sign any csr with SHA-2 when the issuer is using SHA-1

Tags: algorithm, sha1, pki, csr, sha2

I have a rootca using SHA-1 algorithm. Is it possible to generate a subca or sign any csr with SHA-2. Migrating from SHA-1 to SHA-2 is not an option. I want to have cerificate with SHA-2 with its issuer using SHA-1.Is there any link to have more clear picture on the related topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible - a different signature algorithm can be used for each certificate in a chain.

[RFC 5280 section 6.1.4 - Preparation for Certificate i+1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-6.1.4) describes the relevant part of the certification path validation algorithm.  In particular, note:

```
 (f)  Assign the certificate subjectPublicKey algorithm to the
       working_public_key_algorithm variable.
```

This indicates that each certificate may use a different type of public key, which stronly implies that each certificate may be certified using a different signature algorithm.  Furthermore, there is no statement in RFC 5280 that signatures in a certificate path using the same public key type must use the same signature algorithm.

Comment: Thanks a ton for such a complete answer. It is very informative